# How to split matrices in a cell array

Tags: matlab, memory, for-loop

I have a <1 x 29> cell array. Within each cell there is a <310x2000 double> matrix. Because of memory issues I would like to break these matrices up into smaller "chunks" (let's say approx. 5 x 2000 each) starting at row 4 and ending at row 309.

My data is therefore stored in the format of `data{i}(j,:)` where `i` refers to the cell number, and `j` refers to the desired row.

I created a matrix (let's call it A) in which each column gives me the values of the rows I want in each "chunk"

```
4   10  15  20  25
5   11  16  21  26
6   12  17  22  27 ...
7   13  18  23  28
8   14  19  24  29
```

For example, matrix 1 will include rows 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8.

nCells refers to the number of cells I have (29) & nCol refers to the number of columns in matrix A. Therefore:

```
for i = 1:nCells
    for k = 1:nCol
        for j = A(:,k)
           B{i,k}(j,:) = [data{i}(j,:)];
        end
    end
end
```

Unfortunately this gives me the following error:

??? Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

I really appreciate it if someone could tell me what the problem is or/ESPECIALLY if there's a much better way of going about doing this because I run into memory problems:

??? Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Comment: a 29x310x3000 matrix should take about 143 Mb, why do you need to use a cell array if all the dimensions are similar?

Comment: Everything else I would like to do would get very messy without cells. Within each cell there is a row (the contents of which are not constant across cells) with which I use strfind to find the location of particular triggers that I then use to separate the columns in which they occur. For every i (1:nCells) this value changes. I know this isn't very clear but what would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the error you are getting is a result of how for loop indices are taken out of an array. In your third nested loop, you are setting `j` to a column vector. If you replaced this with `A(:,k)'`, then it would probably work. See the following demonstration:

```
>> for i=([1;2;3;4]), disp(['i=' int2str(i)]); end;
??? Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.


>> for i=([1,2,3,4]), disp(['i=' int2str(i)]); end;
i=1
i=2
i=3
i=4
```

Second, you might want to do this a different way. My first instinct is to make a function such as this:

```
>> splitcell = @(C,range)(cellfun( @(X)(X(range,:)), C, 'UniformOutput', false) )
```

This uses the excellent `cellfun` command to call a function on each element of a cell array. Here, we are using matlab's anonymous function syntax (the `@` part) to make a function that takes in a matrix and slices it with a given range. You can make `splitcell` a normal function in its own m-file, I just used `@` here for compactness. `splitcell` has the following usage:

```
>> data = cell(1,5);
>> X = [1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8;9,10,11,12;13,14,15,16]

X =

 1     2     3     4
 5     6     7     8
 9    10    11    12
13    14    15    16

>> for i=1:5, data{i} = (X+i*ones(4)); end;
>> data{1:2}

ans =

 2     3     4     5
 6     7     8     9
10    11    12    13
14    15    16    17


ans =

 3     4     5     6
 7     8     9    10
11    12    13    14
15    16    17    18

>> data2 = splitcell(data,3:4)

data2 = 

[2x4 double]    [2x4 double]    [2x4 double]    [2x4 double]    [2x4 double]

>> data2{1:2}

ans =

10    11    12    13
14    15    16    17


ans =

11    12    13    14
15    16    17    18
```

Comment: That's fantastic. Thanks a lot. I'm pretty new to matlab and I don't fully understand what the function is doing, I'd appreciate if you could expand on it a bit. Thanks!